# How to open multiple psd files to a single fireworks doctument?

Tags: photoshop, fireworks

When I tried dragging multiple psd files to my FireWorks, it opens each psd files as an individual document. I would like to get multiple psd files to open in a single FireWords document but different page.

Or at least merge multiple FireWorks files into one FireWorks document.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the PSD files on top of the open document (on the canvas). It works perfectly in Fireworks CS5 and I can bring in as many PSD files as I want into a single Fireworks document. Not sure about older versions, though.